# Flutter parsing datetime off by a day

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

While setting up a users birthdate, I get a date that is one day behind the stored date in the database.

For example
*John Doe's birthdate:* `1997-12-25T00:00:00+03:00`
*Flutter's DateTime.parse() date:* `1997-12-24`

Help needed please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DateTime value in the local time zone.

```
    final datetimeParsed = DateTime.parse('1997-12-25T00:00:00+03:00').toLocal();
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    final String formatted = formatter.format(datetimeParsed);
    print(formatted);
```

Answer (score 2):

My initial guess would be that the time is not being parsed either from or to the same time zone that you originally stored it in. The `parse()` function can take an optional time zone (as described [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html)) so maybe confirm the time zone is the same in every link of the chain.

Another thing to consider is Daylight savings, as that would could shift the time one way or another dependant on that.

It's possible that the offset for either of these factors is large enough to roll over to the day behind or the day before.

To get Flutter to parse the time as UTC, append a `Z` to the end, for example:

```dart
DateTime.parse(datetime + 'Z'); // UTC time
```

For any other time, you need to specify the hours difference, not a time zone, like so;

```dart
DateTime.parse(datetime + '+02:00'); // +2 hour difference ahead of UTC time
```

You also use `.isUTC` to check if a date is interpreted as UTC and `.toLocal()` to get the local time zone equivalent of the UTC date.

Comment: I'm also thinking it's about different timezones as I have tried playing with the timezones and I find that it gives me different answers... Is there a way of passing a timezone into the parse method of DateTime?

Comment: See my edit @emanuelsanga

Comment: the time comes already with its hours difference, +03:00... I think this might be the culprit as it might be reducing three hours behind